# Read A Folder And Split Sub-Folder Names Into MySQL Inserts

Tags: php, mysql, directory

I have a folder named "Comics" and sub folders in that directory with the names of comics + the issue

Example:

```
/Comics <-- Main Folder
    /Amazing Spider-Man 129 <-- Sub Folder
    /Hellblazer 100 <-- Sub Folder
    /Zatanna 01 <-- Sub Folder
```

Now what i want to do is scan the Comics directory and output each folder name as a mysql insert query. The actual folder name needs to be seperated as "Comic Name" & "Comic Issue".

Example Query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES ('Amazing Spider-Man', '129')");
```

I got this far and now i want to add a query check to see if the comic exists or not.

```
<?php
    $main_folder = 'K:/Comics/'; // should be K:\Comics\ but I changed it because of the highlighting issue
    $folders = glob($main_folder.'* [0-9]*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    $comics_series = array();
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        $comics_series[] = preg_split('/(.+)\s(\d+)/', str_replace($main_folder, '', $folder), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }

    $values = array();
    foreach($comics_series as $pair){
        $values[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($pair[0])."', '".((int) $pair[1])."')";
    }

    $check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comics WHERE name='".$values[0]."' AND issue='".$values[1]."'");
    if ($check_query == '0'){
        $query = 'INSERT INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values);
        $result = mysql_query($query);
            echo ($result) ? 'Inserted successfully' : 'Failed to insert the values';
    }
    ?>
```

is that the right format for the query_check?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: so you have the issue's of the comic inside the sub folders?  Are the issues folders themselves, or are they documents that you want to store in the db?

Comment: /comics holds sub-folders named with the comics name+issue, inside those subfolders are images, i just want to scan the main directory and take the folder names and insert them into mysql.

Comment: I've got to agree with @Catfish - what have you tried? Where are you stuck?  Otherwise this questions sounds a lot like "code this for me for free"

Comment: I added what i have... Sorry didn't mean to make it sound like i needed it totally coded for me :D just stuck on splitting the file name into name + issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
$main_folder = './Comics'; // should be K:\Comics\ but I changed it because of the highlighting issue
$folders = glob($main_folder.'* [0-9]*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

$comics_series = array();
foreach($folders as $folder){
    $comics_series[] = preg_split('/(.+)\s(\d+)/', str_replace($main_folder, '', $folder), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

$values = array();
foreach($comics_series as $pair){
    $values[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($pair[0])."', '".((int) $pair[1])."')";
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO comics (name, issue) VALUES '.implode(',', $values);
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo ($result) ? 'Inserted successfully' : 'Failed to insert the values';
?>
```

Comment: @Matthew Warner: Have you set-up a connection to your database at the top of your php script? Like `<?php $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');`...

Comment: @Matthew Warner: Try adding `echo $query;` just before the last `echo`, and let me know what is the output.

Comment: i got it working, the directory needed to be changed, i tried K:\Comics\ and thats what gave me the error, changed it to K:/Comics/ and it works flawlessly!!! thank you.

Comment: would this be a correct statment to check if the comic is there or not? `$check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comics WHERE name='".$values[0]."' AND issue='".$values[1]."'");`

Comment: @Matthew Warner: Why not have a `UNIQUE` constraint imposed on `(name,issue)`, and then do `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE`? I think it would be better if you wrote a different question for that, because there are other details needed (e.g. table schema, indexes, unique constraints) etc...

Comment: @Matthew Warner: Nope, that's not correct. `$values` array will contain values like `('Amazing Spider-Man','129')`. On the other hand `$comics_series` will contain sub-arrays like `$comics_series[0] = array(0 => 'Amazing Spider-Man', 1 => '129')`.

Comment: so `name='".$comics_series[0]."' AND issue='".$comics_series[1]."'` would be the correct way?

Comment: @rackemup420: Answered on your other question, take a look there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just stuck on splitting the comic name plus issue, check out the [explode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) function

If you are struggling with file/folder traversal, I suggest taking a look at [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). It's much easier.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('K:\Comics')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

            $comicName = null;
            $pieces = explode(' ', $file); // explode the $file

            // if the last element is a number..
            if(is_numeric(end($pieces))) {
                $comicIssue = end($pieces);  // set the issue to a variable
                array_pop($pieces);          // remove the last element of the array

                // loop through the rest of the array and put the pieces back together 
                foreach($pieces as $value) {
                    $comicName .= " $value"; // append the next array element to $comicName
                }
            } else {
                echo "not issue number";
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

?>

Comment: I really dont see a way to use explode right, cant use a space because some of the Comics Names have spaces in them, is there a way to check up until a number appears? and what if there wasnt a number there at all?

Comment: You could use an explode and then grab the last element in the exploded array. That would be the issue number.

Comment: what if there was no issue # and it was just the comic name, would it still work?

Comment: You could check with the is_numeric function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: I'v edited my answer. See if that steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\scan.php on line 15 <-- that line is `if(is_numeric(end($pieces)) {`